# Laravel Intervention memory leak?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, memory-leaks

I'm trying to upload image to my localhost right now. It had no problem, If it's a small image(Not over 1 MB). But when i try uploading about 3MB Image. Php said

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 18048 bytes) in C:\Users\Tharit\Desktop\Work\Pixelbar\Code\ecompro\vendor\intervention\image\src\Intervention\Image\Gd\Decoder.php on line 115

It shouldn't be this much.This is code,in image upload part.

```
        if (Input::hasFile('profile_picture'))
            {
                $old_profile_pic= $user->profile_pic;
                $profile_picture = Input::file('profile_picture');
                $profile_picture_size=getimagesize($profile_picture);
                if($profile_picture_size[0]>$profile_picture_size[1])
                {
                    $mainside = $profile_picture_size[1];
                    $cordx=($profile_picture_size[0]-$profile_picture_size[1])/2;
                    $cordx=(int) $cordx;
                    $cordy=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    $mainside = $profile_picture_size[0];
                    $cordy=($profile_picture_size[1]-$profile_picture_size[0])/2;
                    $cordy=(int) $cordy;
                    $cordx=0;
                }
                $filename  = time() .$user->id . '.' . $profile_picture->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $path = public_path('img/user/' . $filename);
                Image::make($profile_picture->getRealPath())
                            ->crop($mainside,$mainside,$cordx , $cordy)
                            ->resize(100, 100)
                            ->save($path);
                $user->profile_pic = 'img/user/'.$filename;
                if($old_profile_pic != 'img/user/default_profile.gif')
                    {$imagecheck=1;}
            }
```

Comment: I suspect that the problem is in your resizing of the image. If this is using gd, then you need to allow image height x width x 4 bytes of memory for both pre and post resize images

Comment: @MarkBaker you mean pre+post?

Comment: I mean you need to allow enough memory to have both the full size image and the thumbnail in PHP memory at the same time

Comment: The memory usage to create the new image will be much larger then the uploaded images size. Most likely your uploaded image is in a compressed format. When you run this manipulation, it is creating a true color image, so the memory usage will be something like Height * Width * Channels * (magical constant); So its possible that the image you are uploading, once decompressed, takes up a lot more memory then you would expect. 

The "Magical constant" in this case is 1.7 (taken from http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php#99623);

Comment: @StephenMtl That's a new thing to me. I should learn more! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

check your php.ini file for this line

upload_max_filesize=1M

and change it to upload_max_filesize=10M

or change "1M" to any other required file size in MBs

Comment: I've changed it 5M, but that didn't fix. I think it's about memory_limit which set to 128M right now, But i dont thing upload 3M image would take that much. Does it?

Comment: No its not about memory_limit. But if your upload_max_filesize was 1M before, then you will need to restart your server after making the changes for it to take effect

Comment: Yes, I'va changed it before this already, i thing it's bot a problem

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of parameters that you have to set in the php ini to make large file uploads possible. They are:

```
upload_max_filesize
post_max_size
max_input_time
max_execution_time
memory_limit
```

You should find helpful comments to set them in the php ini file.

Plus, its a memory error so I think it has nothing to do with file upload. memory_limit should fix it. Try setting memory_limit to -1 to assign unlimited memory and figure out if its really a memory problem.

Comment: I know it would work if i set a memory limit. But isn't too much to upload 3M image, to 128M memory limit php? Sorry ,but i really dont know. I dont kind of understand these memory thing.

Comment: And i think set memory limit to unlimit isn't a good way to do.

Comment: Can you give the exact line of code to see if I can figure out the problem ? `C:\Users\Tharit\Desktop\Work\Pixelbar\Code\ecompro\vendor\intervention\image\src\Intervention\Image\Gd\Decoder.php on line 115`

Comment: $canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height); this is a code on line 115 , You can see a full page on https://github.com/Intervention/image/blob/master/src/Intervention/Image/Gd/Decoder.php   It's a part of laravel package;Intervention